# Type mismatch: cannot convert from DLL<E>.Node<E> to DLL<E>.Node<E>

Tags: java, project

I am working on implementing a doubly linked list with a nested node class. I am getting a type mismatch error due to the generic nature of the class. Since the nested class is not a static class, I thought it would use the generic type operator from the top-line class.

```
public class DLL <E> {
    
    public class Node<E>{
        private E element;
        private Node<E> prev;
        private Node<E> next;
        
        public <E> Node (E element, Node <E> prev, Node<E> next){
            this.element = element; // Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from E to E
            this.prev = prev; // Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from DLL<E>.Node<E> to DLL<E>.Node<E>
            this.next = next;// Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from DLL<E>.Node<E> to DLL<E>.Node<E>
        }
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to write:

```
public Node(E element, Node<E> prev, Node<E> next) {
```

instead of

```
public <E> Node(E element, Node<E> prev, Node<E> next) {
```

This is a constructor, so it does not need `<E>`. Leaving it as the first one should work. Depending on whether or not you want to make another type parameter, you can change `<E>` to something other than the letter E (to reduce confusion with the other class), or you can simply delete it if you don't need another type parameter.
Example of using lowercase e instead of uppercase E:

```
public class DLL <E> {

    public class Node<e> {
        private E element;
        private Node<e> prev;
        private Node<e> next;

        public Node(E element, Node<e> prev, Node<e> next) {
            this.element = element;
            this.prev = prev;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redeclare the generic type `E`. The Node constructor should use the generic type `E` from the outer `DLL<E>` class. Here is the solution:

```
public class DLL<E> {
    
    public class Node {
        private E element;
        private Node prev;
        private Node next;
        
        public Node(E element, Node prev, Node next) {
            this.element = element;
            this.prev = prev;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

}
```